# Server to client update without constant/persistent request from client Websocket programming

Tags: php, html, node.js, websocket

Perhaps I did not fully understand the answers in related questions. I got the long polling ,reverse ajax concept but the thing is this:

My current set up is in my local unit, I am the client and I am the server. I can successfully establish connection to my server and I can send back to my client a message once connection is established, now another scenario comes in, I would just want the server to continuously update my client after establishing the connection. For simplicity purpose, say I would like   my client to be updated with the server time so everytime the minute changes, the server sends the most current time to the client(provided that the connection is already established).

I am using node.js and socket.io. The following are my codes:

CLIENT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<meta charset="utf-8" />  
<title>WebSocket Testing</title>  
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
var socket = new io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:8080");
socket.on('connect', function(){

//  socket.on('news', function (data) {
//  socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });


        socket.on("test",function(data){
            alert(data);
        });


    socket.onmessage =  function (event) {
        console.log(event.data);
    }

});
console.log(socket);
</script>  
<h2>WebSocket Test</h2>  
<div id="output"></div>  
</html>
```

SERVER:

```
var socketOptions = {
            transportOptions: {
                    'xhr-polling': {
                            closeTimeout: 20000000, //20 mins
                            timeout: 20000000  //20 mins
                    }
            }
    };

var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , url = require('url')
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app,socketOptions)

  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(8080);

function handler (req, res) {
    var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
    console.log("ERROR: "+err)
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

  //  res.writeHead(200);
    //res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': path == 'json.js' ? 'text/javascript' : 'text/html'})
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    console.log("THIS IS IT");
    res.end(data);
  });

}

console.log(io);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
//  socket.send("testing lang kung nagsesend");
//  console.log("connection");
//  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
//  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
//    console.log(data);
//  });


    socket.emit("test","Test connection message established,send and received");
});
```

What do I do with my server codes? I can notice that almost all code samples are in php format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a setInterval with a function in the callback what you want it to do ever set seconds after the `connection` has been fired. You are looking for something like this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    setInterval(function(){
        // do a socket emit here to give data to client
    },1000);
}
```

Comment: it will set interval after each connection from client. Should it be rather after app.listen(8080); ?

Comment: Yes this is also possible! but depends on what you are looking for. Also if you use this approach be sure to remove the interval when the disconnect event has been fired to keep it clean.

Comment: ive considered that as well but wouldnt it be heavy for my server if that's the case? What if the scenario is a change from a variable value occured, shall I apply a regular logic of if..then statement? Perhaps my question is does socket io have something like a function of continuous feeding data to its server?

Comment: "to its server?" Do you mean clients? if so, this probably is the best way to do it (I don't know any other). If you want all the clients to have the same variables, go for @pawlakppp 's solution. The only difference is that the interval is set once and not 1 for all clients that are connected (better for your load)

Comment: hi I just got back to my desk after a long weekend and gave this a try. I dunno if it is a good practice though, but thanks coz it worked like magic  :) ...